# AJAX returns Error (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to pass data to controller via AJAX

Here is script

```
 <script>
    $('.click').on('click', function () {
        $('.content').toggle();
    });
    var counter = 0;
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#save').click(function () {
            save();
        });
    });
    function save()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: { question1: $('#question1').val(),
                    question2: $('#question2').val(),
                    question3: $('#question3').val(),
                    question4: $('#question4').val(),
                    question5: $('#question5').val(),
                    question6: $('#question6').val(),
                    question7: $('#question7').val(),
                    question8: $('#question8').val(),
                    question9: $('#question9').val(),
                    question10: $('#question10').val()
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Questions")',
            success: function (da) {
                if (da.Result === "Success") {
                    alert('saved sucessfully');


                } else {

                    alert( 'Error'+ da.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (da) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
}


</script>
```

Here is controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string question1, string question2, string question3, string question4, string question5, string question6, string question7, string question8, string question9, string question10)
    {
        QuestionBlock question = new QuestionBlock
        {
            Question1 = question1,
            Question2 = question2,
            Question3 = question3,
            Question4 = question4,
            Question5 = question5,
            Question6 = question6,
            Question7 = question7,
            Question8 = question8,
            Question9 = question9,
            Question19 = question10,

        };
        db.QuestionBlocks.Add(question);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But when I run function on button click I have this error in console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) and Controller name. Also alert says Error
```

Where is may be trouble?

I think I pass data correctly to controller

Comment: So what is the error on the server? What is the error in the network request?

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) and Controller name`

Comment: You need to figure out the error that is on the server.... It does not like something with the data you are sending up.

Comment: How I can do this?@epascarello

Comment: Do you not have serverside logs?

Comment: Nope, I make it on local host@epascarello

Comment: hm. you talk about network console? @epascarello

Comment: db.SaveChanges(); Have this@epascarello

Comment: so set breakpoints and debug if you are working remotely.

Comment: That db looks fishy

Comment: do you have a controller in more than 1 area called questions? if you do then you need to include the area in your url action call so that it can be resolved. Also shouldn't `Question19 = question10,
` be `Question10 = question10`

Comment: all ok, new Entry is created. but it create id and not enter questions@bilpor

Comment: I resolve problem@bilpor